# mkdir $variable/$variable2 does not work

Tags: linux, bash, scripting

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Iveskite teksto faila is kurio norite paimti pirma eilute"
read failas
echo "Nurodykite kataloga kuriame noresite sukurti naujus katalogus"
read direktorija
mkdir -p $direktorija
head -n1 "$failas" | while read pavadinimas
do
mkdir $direktorija/$pavadinimas
done
```

my $failas is:

`pirmas antras trecias ketvirtas penktas sestas
eilutes i kurias mano scriptas nereguoja`

So the problem is, that mkdir `$direktorija/$pavadinimas` does not work. It only creates first folder in $direktorija/$pavadinimas, and all others goes directly to $direktorija, instead of going to $direktorija/$pavadinimas

What I want to do is create:

`$direktorija/pirmas
$direktorija/antras
$direktorija/trecias
$direktorija/ketvirtas`

Comment: Every directory name read from the file `$failas` will be created as a subdirectory in `$direcktorija`. Do you instead want each new name to be a subdirectory of the previously created directory? For instance, if the first line of the file is `a b c`, do you want to create `$direktorija/a/b/c`?

Comment: `mkdir $variable/$variable2` does work and it is doing exactly what is assigned to it. The problem is you aren't expressing properly what you want, not in the code, and not in post. give a little explanation of what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `read` command to read the first line of the file into an array,
treating the line as a list of space-separated names. Then, iterate over the array to create each directory under `$direktorija`.

```
echo "Iveskite teksto faila is kurio norite paimti pirma eilute"
read failas
echo "Nurodykite kataloga kuriame noresite sukurti naujus katalogus"
read direktorija
mkdir "$direktorija"
# Read line into an array
read -a pavadinimai < "$failas"

for pavadinimas in "${pavadinimai[@]}"; do
    mkdir "$direktorija/$pavadinimas"
done
```

Comment: I will test in few minutes. what does IFS=/ means, mate? Thanks for trying to help.

Comment: For an array `a`, `${a[*]}` expands to a single string with each element separated by the first character in the value of `IFS`. By default, that's a space. By setting `IFS=/`, the array expands to a string with the elements separated by a `/` instead. I use a subshell `(...)` so that you don't have to worry about restoring the previous value of `IFS`.

Comment: line 11: syntax error: unexpected end of file when I use your script

Comment: Oops, I forgot the closing `)` on the last line.

Comment: Hmm, It works. But it creates $direktorija/$pavadinimas/a/b/c/d/e/f/g/
What I want to do is create $direktorija/$pavadinimas/a
$direktorija/$pavadinimas/b
$direktorija/$pavadinimas/c

Comment: Where does `pavadinimas` come from, though? Should the input line `a b c d` then produce `a/b`, `a/c`, and `a/d`?

Comment: `pavadinimas` comes from `head -n1 "$failas"` I take first line of the file, and I want to create new folders with names like in the first line (as much words - that much folders, each word - one folder)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77123/discussion-between-semkius-and-chepner).

Comment: Please update your question with the exact contents of `failas` and the exact set of directories you expect to created. It's not clear from your original code just how the input of a single line from the file should be treated.

Comment: OK, I think I understand your problem now. I've updated the answer. `read` reads a single line from the input, and `head -n1` supplied only a single line (which consists of multiple words). My new solution reads that single line into an array, one word per element, then loops over the array to create the directories.

Comment: You're welcome! And I now know more Lithuanian than I used to :)